# Debian 11, works fine but strange systemd error happen

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I'm on Debian 11, on a Virtual Machine using kvm
My user can login via console, ssh and lightdm.
But there is an error with systemd

```
sudo systemctl status user@1000.service 
● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─sysfs.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-09-06 20:20:08 UTC; 50min ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 897 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 12ms

set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[897]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user user(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[897]: Failed to determine supported controllers: No such process
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[897]: Failed to allocate manager object: No such process
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
set 06 20:20:08 host systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 1000.
```

I see the service try to exec this line

```
grep -i exec /lib/systemd/system/user@.service
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

I try to debug the service

```
/lib/systemd/systemd --user --log-level=debug

systemd 247.3-6 running in user mode for user 1000/user. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/reg', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/dir', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/fifo', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/sock', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/chr', ignoring: File exists
Failed to create '/run/user/1000/systemd/inaccessible/blk', ignoring: Operation not permitted
Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/, full unified hierarchy
Failed to determine root cgroup, ignoring cgroup memory limit: No such process
RLIMIT_MEMLOCK is already as high or higher than we need it, not bumping.
Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/, full unified hierarchy
Unified cgroup hierarchy is located at /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope.
Failed to create /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope/init.scope control group: Permission denied
Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
```

Any solution?

Comment: It seems this is a side effect of using `hidepid=2` on `/proc` https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12955

Comment: After container got restarted (probably host system upgrade) by the hosting service I got numerous periodic `Failed to create /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/init.scope control group: Permission denied` in log, my debian installation is already up to date with no more updates available. It turns out after a few reboots, things get solved without extra tweak required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution/workaround found, probably is a bug of systemd.
With this cmdline on grub "systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
all works fine

```
vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="apparmor=1 security=apparmor systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"

update-grub2
shutdown -r now
```

we make some checks, all works fine as expected

```
systemctl is-active user@1000.service 
active
sudo systemctl list-units --state failed 
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.
```

Comment: `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` also fixed similar errors `Failed to determine supported controllers: Operation not permitted` / `Failed to allocate manager object: Operation not permitted` on `systemd --user` startup (occurs since upgrade from raspberry pi os buster to bullseye with `hidepid=1/noaccess`). what are the implications of this change? (`man systemd` only mentions "fall back to hybrid or full legacy cgroup hierarchy")